# Collapse sidebar (Table of Contents, left side) section

Tags: docusaurus

How can I add the 'Collapse sidebar' button to my own Docusaurus website, as shown below?

[image: collapse sidebar_toc]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your `docusaurus.config.js`, you need to add the parameter `hideableSidebar: true`, in the `themeConfig` category.

**EXAMPLE**

```
(module.exports = { // start of the module.export declaration
[…]

    themeConfig: {
        hideableSidebar: true,
        […] 
    }

[…] 
}); // end of the module-export declaration
```

---

**REFERENCE**

https://docusaurus.io/docs/sidebar#hideable-sidebar